# How does UiLifeCycleHelper utilize LoginButton in facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to learn android development using the facebook SDK.

Today I tried the Login part of it.
However the thing is I have a lot of confusion in this area since I do not understand how the uiLifeCycleHelper and the LoginButton interact.

From the samples :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="co.chintan.fbtest.SplashFragment"
>

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/login_button"
    android:text="@string/get_started"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This was the login screen and it has a login button as evident from the code.

The main activity flow is like this :

- The onCreate method has a uiLifeCyleHelper that takes in the activity and statusCallback object.
- The Session.StatusCallBack object listens for session changes and an inner class implements the onChange method which shows the authenticated UI if there is a session or the Non-Authenticated UI if there is no Session.

Now my question is how does the uiLifeCycleHelper use the LoginButton created in the layout xml, since there is no implementation of the LoginButton in the MainActivity class that I created, even then there seems to be a listener for the LoginButton, as when I click on the login button, I can login and create a session and load my authenticated UI.

I saw the SDK source but I do not see any listener for the loginButton even there.

Comment: I hope this helps https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2

Comment: Hi @krishna I did read it. I could not get an answer to this question from it.Thanks for replying though

Answer (score 0):

The uiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult method passes the results of the login over to the Session object. The LoginButton contains a SessionTracker (an internal class in the SDK) that keeps track of session changes, which is how it knows when the login succeeds.